# Trick kernel into having a connected keyboard

Tags: raspbian, kernel, keyboard, emulation, retropie

I have a Raspberry Pi B running Raspbian. I'm using it to create [this](https://superpiboy.wordpress.com/) for my little brother. I'm using Adafruit's Retrogame code (found [here](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Retrogame)) to receive GPIO inputs and convert them into keyboard inputs. I've been able to configure it to work with a keyboard plugged in, but as soon as a keyboard is unplugged, the pi no longer receives input.

Is there a way to trick the pi into thinking that a keyboard is connected all the time? Is there a kernel module I can install or a package library that will do it all for me?

Comment: I'd personally try [uinput](http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput). I have similar requirements as yours and started to investigate in that direction.

Answer (score 2):

Posting as an answer.

You can try [uinput](http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput) as it is designed to inject events into the input event queue.